# HAL_LED_MODE_ON

Tags: c, embedded, iar

it me AGAIN. Sorry guys, I am just a newbie in embedded and I am learning the basic first. Well, I am playing with the LED and I found out the header file define this `#define HAL_LED_MODE_ON  0x01` `HAL_LED_MODE_BLINK  0x02`. Could anyone tell me what is the meaning of this? WHAT is the hex number represent? Kinda confuse and I am using CC2540EB and using IAR workbench 8051 for the programming part. Thanks =).

Comment: The numbers depend entirely on your hardware.

Comment: or post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows how those defines are used.

Comment: The numbers could be the pins numbers, they could be other settings, it's how they're used in your code that matters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HAL_LED_MODE_ON` and `HAL_LED_MODE_BLINK` values in `HalLedSet` function, i.e. `HalLedSet( HAL_LED_2, HAL_LED_MODE_BLINK )`

I recommend that you first read the HAL library manual, or review smilar source code for your hardware.